# How to perform deep populate mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

this is my question.js and user.js schema model with mongoose as below, could anyone help how to populate all the username lists in array object of likes:[] with Node js because I was facing this problem almost 2 weeks now, I could not populate the username from a user inside likes. Please, I appreciate your suggestion.

[question schema model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymF5A.png)

[user schema model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RppHm.png)

Comment: Please type in your sample code and/or error code. If possible do not post them with pictures. Contributors will reluctant to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To populate user details, Please use

```
Post.findOne( { _id: id } )
    .populate( "user" )
    .populate( "likes.user" );
```

To get liked post, please use

```
Post.find({ "likes": { "$gt": 0 } }, function(err, data) {
})
```

or using where, here may get error if likes fields is missing or empty, so please check if it is exists

```
Post.find( {$where:'this.likes.length>0'} )
```

so please use where and exists

```
Post.find( {likes: {$exists:true}, $where:'this.likes.length>0'} )
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and got it working using your model. If you are using `user` only you can directly call `.populate("user")` but if its nested you need to do `.populate("likes.user")`

```js
Post.findOne( { _id: id } ).populate( "user" ).populate( "likes.user" );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and fast response, Ratnadeep Bhattacharyya :). Now, I able to populate the likes with user->name :), but if I want to return respond with the only array of likes inside the post schema, is it possible to do that? Because base on my code below it returns the whole post, but I want the only array of likes to be returned. ```js const likes = await Post.findOne({ _id: req.params.postId }) .populate('user', ['name']) .populate('likes.user', ['name']); return res.status(200).json(likes); ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thank you to Ratnadeep Bhattacharyya, now I able to populate username in likes array object and also able to return the only a specific array of likes. Below is the working code: 
Happy Coding, Jonh

```js
//@route api/post/get/likes
router.get('/get/likes/:postId', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //check if post exist
    const likes = await Post.findOne({ _id: req.params.postId })
      .populate('user', ['name'])
      .populate('likes.user', ['name']);
    return res.status(200).json(likes.likes);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Server error' });
  }
});
```